# Special character in azure storage queue message

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I have this simple code:

```
  QueueClient azQueue = new QueueClient(@"<connection string>", "test-queue");                
  azQueue.SendMessage("test®test");
```

and it fails with message: "Retry failed after 6 tries."
If I remove ® character from string it sends message with no issue.
Please help me handle special characters properly.

Comment: You'll most likely need to encode the message or get it from another place (like a DB)

Comment: originally I'm getting string from db. it is how I found this issue. Here just simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using newer SDK `Azure.Storage.Queues` which does not automatically encode the message in Base64 like the previous ones `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue` or `WindowsAzure.Storage` (deprecated). So it's better to encode your message like below. Also refer this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11358 and there is also a feature request https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10242.

```
  QueueClient azQueue = new QueueClient(@"<connection string>", "test-queue");                
  azQueue.SendMessage(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test®test")));
```

Comment: Yes I'm using latest Azure.Storage.Queues 12.4.2. So I have to encode all messages to base64? And max size of message will be encoded to base64, right? Strange it is not mentioned in ms docs.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately current doc does not mention this clearly. There is also a feature request https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10242.